# Europe not available in Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

When trying to create a VM in Azure, I cannot create the VM in Europe (screenshot below).
Can someone kindly advise why is that the case and what action I can take?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like you're in the right place.  Are you in the old CP or in the new Portal?  DNS Name - .cloudapp.net suggests that you're trying to set up an app service.

Comment: I think he is using the old portal. It looks like Azure creates an "under the hood" cloud service for VMs.

Comment: Somehow if I use the new portal ... I can select Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact Azure Support. Sometimes some datacenters become unavailable for some subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for the tip. had tried to do that but you need to pay and I am using the trial at this stage :). I think I managed using the new portal. No idea why I cannot select Europe using the old portal.

Comment: A few months ago I had the same issue and it happened on both portals.

Answer (score 1):

Azure trial accounts can be limited to some regions, the western europe datacenter is quite full, mobile apps wasnt available in western europe for the same reason.